# Complex Vlookup/ VBA function or Macro Needed For "if contains text then vlookup"

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have a problem, http://goo.gl/i82eA this is sample data that I have with the required output. Currently I have a user defined function that is manually using many if statements to do the job but I want to be able to do something like a vlookup if it finds a certain color in a colum and return the colormap coresponding to it.

Or use like a filter function like filter all cells that contain Blue and give the destination cell with blue, and then run next filter with next value in an table of colors.

```
Color   ColorMap     Text             Required Output
blue    blue         Deep Blue Shoe   Blue (if Text contains blue return blue)
red     red          Deep red Shoe    red (if Text contains red return red) etc
tan     brown        Tan Shoe         brown
navy    blue         Navy Emp Shoe    blue
jade    green        Jade Shoe        green
plum    red          Plum Red Shoe    multicoloured (if Text contains more than 1 color return multicolored)
```

So input should be like 2 columns for the data to be looked up 1 column for searching and the 1 column is the destination column if its a function

```
function_name(lookup_text,lookup_table,destination)
```

Thanks in advance

ps: here is the code Im using now

Code:

```
Function Colormap(strVal As String) As String

If (InStr(strVal, "red") > 0) Then
    Colormap = "Red"
End If

If (InStr(strVal, "Beige") > 0) Then
    Colormap = "Beige"
End If

etc..

End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks up the `Text` value and returns the `ColorMap` value; if more than one match is found "multicolored" is returned. Note: This is an array formula--enter it with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

`=IF(SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A$2:A$7,C2)),1,0))>1,"multicolored",LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(A$2:A$7,C2),B$2:B$7))`

Here's a function that does the same thing. It requires that the reference table be a named range. Call the function like this: `=ColorMap(C2,"ColorTable")` where `ColorTable` is a named range referring to `$A$2:$B$7`.

```
Public Function ColorMap(LookupValue As Variant, LookupTableName As String) As String
    Dim vTable As Variant
    Dim lIdx As Long
    Dim sColor As String

    ' transfer lookup table to 2D range & loop through to find matches
    vTable = Names(LookupTableName).RefersToRange.Value
    For lIdx = LBound(vTable, 1) To UBound(vTable, 1)
        If UCase$(LookupValue) Like "*" & UCase$(vTable(lIdx, 1)) & "*" Then
            sColor = sColor & ", " & vTable(lIdx, 2)
        End If
    Next lIdx
    If Len(sColor) > 2 Then sColor = Mid$(sColor, 3)
    ' map multiple matches to "multicolored"
    If InStr(sColor, ",") > 0 Then sColor = "multicolored"
    ColorMap = sColor
End Function
```

Comment: wow! thanks!! that works awesome can you break the formula down for me? is there a way i can make that into a function?

how can i get the vba equivalent for that if possible?


THANKS AGAIN!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: The updated version handles the "multicolored" return value. Do you still need a function? If so, that's probably more straight-forward but of course requires VBA and enabling of macros.

Comment: Hi Rachel, hmm i tried the formula.. but its not giving multicoloured for Plum Red Shoes - gives red only. Thanks! and yes a function would be easier and macro enabling is no problem!

Comment: Forgot to note that the formula is an array formula--enter it with Ctrl+Shift+Enter instead of just Enter.

Comment: Rachel UR A GENIUS!!! :) <3 thank you sooo much!!!! I should hire you we need people like you to help with automation !!

Comment: Hey Rachel, I tried making a named Range but i get #VALUE! as the output? am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Also if i drag the formula down for other cells it gives me either 0 or multicoloured.. am i doing something wrong?

Comment: If you are using the first option (pure worksheet function), then make sure your "table" range is fixed by using $ before the row indexes. For example: A$2:A$7 instead of A2:A7.

Comment: Perhaps [this link](http://www.contextures.com/xlnames01.html) will help explain how to do named ranges.

Comment: I got the named range working but when i try it as a function It does not work, here is another scenario. If one of the colors in B column appear in the A colum like so

Bronze brown Bronze Shoes Brown
Brown  brown Brown Shoes  multicoloured

then the result wil be multicoloured for some reason. here is a link to the output http://goo.gl/i82eA look at the red row. Thanks for all your help